# How do I save the XY coordinates of a Binary Image in R?

Tags: r, image-processing, imagej, binary-image

I am trying to save the XY coordinates of a binary image in R similarly to the save "Save XY Coordinates" function in ImageJ. I've looked through several image analysis packages available for R, but haven't yet figured out how to accomplish this.
[image]

Comment: Save the XY coordinates of what?

Comment: Exactly what he said. The phrase "XY coordinates of a binary image" might be meaningful to someone who uses imageJ all the time but it is whooshing over our heads. You are also expect to provide some sort of data/file/link so there is something to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are *many* ways to do the following in R:

```
img_fil <- "~/data/ZjYqw.jpg"
img <- magick::image_read(img_fil)
img_df <- RSAGA::grid.to.xyz(as.matrix(as.raster(img)))

head(img_df)
##   x   y       z
## 1 0 599 #ffffff
## 2 1 599 #ffffff
## 3 2 599 #ffffff
## 4 3 599 #ffffff
## 5 4 599 #ffffff
## 6 5 599 #ffffff
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I went to do this on the image I put above, but when I went to plot the points, the entire plot turned up black. Is there a way to save only the coordinates of the black pixels (those being of a color value of 255)?

Comment: Since I have no idea how you plotted the image it's impossible to help with that. But, if you had used `ggplot2`, then `ggplot(img_df, aes(x, y, color=z)) + geom_point() + scale_color_identity()` should plot it with black & white.